# What is PhoneGap doing with all the HTML CSS and JavaScript stuff?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

as example i build a HTML5 CSS3 and JS app. If i want to run it on an Android phone i have to put all this stuff in the assets www folder and after that i have to import cordova.jar into to the lib and make these changes

```
public class Test  extends DroidGap {

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
```

but what happens. where is this app running?
what is phonegap doing?
please help!

Comment: The web app is running in a webview inside the native app. As a web developer, PhoneGap provides you the basic structure you need to package the native app and access native APIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At runtime, PhoneGap works by instantiating a browser component on the device. This is a chrome-less browser, meaning that it does not have an address-bar or forward/back buttons. The end developer’s application consists of HTML, JavaScript and CSS that are loaded into the browser component. PhoneGap provides a JavaScript API that allows developer code to access device functionality, that is currently not accessible to web sites loaded in the default browser. The web view used by PhoneGap is the same web view used by the native operating system.   On iOS, this is the Objective-C UIWebView class; on Android, this is android.webkit.WebView.

The idea being to display web components, it all starts with a web view! This webview should be able to load HTML (locally or remotely), and run Javascript and CSS. All major smartphones come with an XYZWebView, the only thing you'll have to watch for is the (decreasing) gap in HTML/CSS support between them.

Next step is allowing Javascript code in that webview to call your native code, and vice versa. All platforms can do this, but unfortunately they all do it differently.

```
Android - Java objects are marshalled into the webview, and native methods can be called directly.

iOS - Javascript needs to make a call to a URL with a custom scheme (think native://mycall), which is intercepted by the native code.

Windows 8 - The web view exposes a window.external.notify function that Javascript can call at will.
```

The reverse bridge is usually much easier: if the webview exposes a global javascript function, the native code can simply call it passing any required arguments. The trick just lies in that call being synchronous or not, depending on the platform.